# How can I import a database using command line?

Tags: command-line, mysql, database

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I want to import my database which is located on the server `/var/www/backup.zip`. Also I've SSH access using Putty. Noted that MySQL and phpMyadmin are installed on the server.

When I run this command

```
mysql -u root -p spy < /var/www/backup.zip
```

nothing happens. A newline shows which starts with `->`.

What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: You ran the `mysql` command inside `mysql`?

Comment: @muru Not sure what you mean exactly, but yes, as you see, there is `mysql> ` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe the format is:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file.sql
```

From within mysql:

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```

Comment: well what's the difference between yours *(`mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file.sql`)* and mine *(`mysql -u root -p spy < /var/www/backup.zip`)*?

Comment: @stack that George intends that command to be run in the shell, and not inside mysql. (That's why the rest of the answer is headed by "from **within** mysql".)

Comment: @muru Ah I see. thank you guys. *(btw I think you could say so 30min ago `:)`)*

Comment: in ubuntu you should add ./mysql to access file within xampp's bin folder otherwise it will search for global

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you're trying to run a bash command from within mysql. If you run that command at the regular terminal prompt the format of the command is correct.

The second issue is that you have a zip file and not a SQL file so you need to unzip it first.

[How do I load a sql.gz file to my database?](https://serverfault.com/q/137965/51312) (on Server Fault) explains most of what you need. My answer there should work here too with a slight modification:

```
unzip -p /var/www/backup.zip | mysql -u root -p mydb
```

`unzip -p` unzips to a pipe, so that you can pipe that into your database command. Make sure the zip file only contains one sql file.

`mysql -u root -p mydb` is going to prompt you for a password (the `-p` without a value) and then attempt to pipe in the file data to `mydb` - change the `mydb` to your own database. You shouldn't specify the password in the command line as it then remains in your command history.